# UICollectionViewCell with a button inside of it

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` designed in the interface builder with an touch up action linked to it's source files.

The view class is correctly set to the my custom subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`. The outlet correctly visible in Xcode.

Problem is that the action is not getting fired no matter how i try to fix it.

I've completely ran out of ideas now.

I'm using Xcode5 DP6 and iOS7.

The best part is that everything worked fine until I've decided to create a new interface for my custom cell and removed the old file and create a new one. I updated all the connections and names but it just doesn't work. I've also removed the DerivedData directory in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should have a custom UIButton the size of the cell (should be a custom button which is filled with clear color and no title) and then link the IBAction to the UIViewController of your app. Your IBOutlet to your button should however be a pointer in the UICollectionViewCell subclass. Generally, to figure our which cell fired this, you will set UIButton.tag to the indexPath.row where you are setting the contents of the cell. It works and I have used it many times. Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same issue in Xcode 6 beta 5 on iOS 7.1.2, where it was previously working in Xcode 5.1.1.

Thanks to my version control, I saw this little nugget:

```
-                                    <collectionViewCell opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" reuseIdentifier="SCTutorialCell5" id="03V-Y4-Bha" userLabel="tutorial5" customClass="SCTutorialCell">
546  
-                                        <rect key="frame" x="1280" y="0.0" width="320"** height="568"/>
547  
-                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
    549
+                                    <collectionViewCell opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" reuseIdentifier="SCTutorialCell5" id="T8L-AB-8Je" userLabel="tutorial5" customClass="SCTutorialCell">
    550
+                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
    551
+                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
```

I inserted a new prototype cell into my UICollectionView, but instead of making the new cell like all the others, the beta Xcode set the cell frame to {0, 0, 50, 50} when it should be {1280, 0, 320, 568}

Going into the source code (Right click the storyboard --> View as --> source code) and fixing the XML worked for me.